# How to resize UIScrollView on rotation?

Tags: iphone, rotation

For my project I've created an UIScrollView with an UIImage inside. The Scroll View is as big as the window frame (tab bar application). What I want is to resize the UIScrollView again when the user rotates the device. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the autoresizing mask either in Interface Builder, or through code, depending on which way you created the UIScrollView in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, that was obvious but for some reasons I missed it and thought that I couldn't set the autoresize for the scroll view.